# How to make ArcToolbox as its default?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, arctoolbox

I wrongly deleted Data Management Tools from ArcToolbox in ArcGIS 9.3. Now I can't use some features such as "Dissolve", "Eliminate", etc.

How could I make it as default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the Data management toolbox back into the ArcToolbox panel. Simply right click on the the top node (ArcToolbox) and choose Add Toolbox.

Now I stopped using 9.3 years ago so I can't tell you where the toolbox is located but it will be within the installation folder of ArcMap. That's for you to find the tbx file.

Having re-established the toolbox into ArcToolbox you need to tell ArcMap to make it a **default**. So simply right click on the top node, choose Save settings > to default.